# Why does a sudden voltage drop happen when I connect a solar panel to a TP4506 module?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-charge-controller, voltage, tp4056

I am integrating a solar energy system to my smart greenhouse. The energy system will operate two 12 V, 0.2 A case fans (they draw a maximum of 0.5 A for maximum rpm) and a 5 V, 0.5 A mist maker.

I’m using a 5 W, 18 V solar panel that is charging four 1500 mAh lithium batteries that are connected in parallel. Furthermore, I’m charging them with a TP4056 lithium battery charging module.

Everything is working perfectly fine, and I can charge the batteries using micro-USB connected to the module. However, when I connect the module to the solar panel, the 18 V output drops to approximately 2.3 V, and the module doesn’t operate. I’m not really sure why this voltage drop happens. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Note: This voltage drop happens when the batteries aren’t connected to anything, and still happens when connected to the fans and the mist maker.

Here is a diagram of the circuit. It contains a solar panel, the TP4056, lithium batteries, and a DC-DC booster.
[image]

Comment: This is beside the point, but your solar panel is too low power to continuously operate the whole system. You may already be planning this, but you will need to turn everything off for much of the day to let your batteries charge, or only turn one thing on at a time.

Comment: @imnotarobot thanks for the heads up, but yes, I'm aware that it won't power the system for much time.

Comment: _"I have a DC-DC step-down converter between the panel and the TP4056A but it isn't in the diagram."_ - why did you leave out this critical information?

Comment: Maximum TP4056 voltage is 8 volts. You might have broken it

Answer (score 3):

Solar panels aren't constant voltage sources or anything close to it.  You are seeing the 18 Voc - open circuit voltage.  When you pull current from a solar panel, its voltage will drop with increasing load until you reach 0V and current is Isc - short circuit current.  The 5W figure is at the maximum power point, the combination of output voltage and output current that gives you the greatest overall power.  To fully utilize this panel, you will need a solar panel controller with maximum power point tracking - a specialized DC/DC converter that will adjust its input to keep the solar panel at its MPP while maintaining a stable output voltage.

Comment: So, I can get a solar panel controller like the XH-M60 and connect it between the panel and the lithium batteries to adjust the input, right?

Comment: Also, can I replace this controller with a voltage regulator, such as a 7805 Voltage Regulator 5V / 1A or is using a solar panel controller a must?

Comment: Paint a schematic how you have connected all your devices, battery-cells and voltage regulator to generate 12V and 5V. This would make it more easy to understand what you mean. I have written a answer, but I am really not sure ... did I understand this right or not.

Comment: @MikroPower I added a diagram I made to the question. Please have a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: Your solar panel controller would connect to the TP4056 module unless it has built-in battery charging functionality.  A 7805 does not have MPPT capability and, as a linear regulator, is entirely unsuitable from an efficiency standpoint.

Comment: @vir So, a 7805 would work but would have awful power extraction, right?

Comment: No, because the 7805 doesn't have MPPT.  If your panel drops to 2.3V when loaded then the 7805 will cut out since it "passes on" the load current to the input.

Answer (score 0):

1. The TP4056A allows a input voltage of maximum 8 Volt, if the voltage is higher, then you will destroy this chip. With 18V at his inputs the chip is definitive damaged.
2. Your battery is possibly a device with 4 LiIon-cells in a row.

- Minimum voltage: 4x 3.6V = 12V
- Maximum voltage: 4x 4.2V = 16.8V

You need a stepdown Max-PowerPoint-Module to create out of your 18V a useable voltage for your battery.
Example: [Solar Controller 12V Bluetooth](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005002939750979.html)

With 1.8Ah this are around 26.6Wh and in reality you will get around 18Wh if you do not load the cells to the maximum voltage and not to the minimum voltage.

3. If the cells are really in parallel, then you have the case that the cells are nearly empty (2.3V is near battery-cell-death) and the voltage of the module is breaking in and because of the very bad power-point, the energy is extremely low.
   In your case the current is high and because of this the voltage will drop to nearly nothing, but it must be close to the voltage of the LiIon-cells and if this voltage is 2.3V then you should load them up to minimum 3.0V or better 3.6V !

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Power_Point_Tracking

Comment: I have a DC-DC step-down converter between the panel and the TP4056A but it isn't in the diagram. However, I understand that I have to get a solar regulator to fix the input voltage going to the batteries. Is a XH-M60 suitable for this process?

Comment: You can use the "XH-M60" to generate 5V from the battery, but this is not useable as MPPT module. The MPPT module looks at the input-current and input voltage to adjust the output current in a way that the input delivers always on the maximum possible energy. -> Select "MPPT 18V" https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4000223711128.html

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but the MPPT module in your comment isn't available for me currently. However, I found two modules that I can get but don't know which one is better: XH-M603 or XL401. The XH-M603 looks like the ones I saw online but doesn't mention having MPPT capabilities anywhere. However, it is written in the seller's page that XL401 has MPPT capabilities. Which one is better suited for my use?